# Finding non-trivial sufficient statistic

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I have this question.

To find a sufficient I have to find first the joint pmf of this pmf's?

Let $X_{1}, . . . , X_{n} $be a random sample from the following pmf:
$P(X = k_{1}) = \frac{1 − \theta}{2}$
, $P(X = k_{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$
and $P(X = k_{3}) = \frac{\theta}{2}$
, $0 < \theta < 1$
Find a non-trivial sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

Comment: Write the likelihood as $L(\theta)=\prod_{i:k_i=k_1}(\frac{1-\theta}2)\prod_{i:k_i=k_2} (\frac12)\prod_{i:k_i=k_3}(\frac\theta2)=\cdots$. Can you find a sufficient statistic now?

Comment: I should use the factorization theorem to find the T (sufficient statistic )  from L(θ)?

Comment: Yes of course..

Comment: Now I'm trying this one:  Let X1, . . . , Xn be a random sample from the following pmf.
P(X = 0) = θ, P(X = 1) = 2θ, P(X = 2) = 1 − 3θ, 0 < θ < 1
I start L(θ)=L(θ)=∏i:ki=0(θ)∏i:ki=1(2θ)∏i:ki=2(1-3θ) but how you guys factorize the next passage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L(\theta)=\left(\frac{1-\theta}{2} \right)^{\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{k_1}(x_i)}
\left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right)^{\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{k_3}(x_i)}
\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^{n-\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{k_1}(x_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{k_3}(x_i)}
$$
$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{k_1}(x_i),\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{k_3}(x_i)\right)$ is a sufficient statistic.

Comment: thank you for the help!

Comment: You are welcome!