# Finding Sufficient Statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, sufficient-statistics

Let X1, . . . , Xn be a random sample from the following pmf.
P(X = 0) = θ, P(X = 1) = 2θ, P(X = 2) = 1 − 3θ, 0 < θ < 1/3
Find a non-trivial sufficient statistic.

I start like this:
 L(θ)=L(θ)=∏i:ki=0(θ)∏i:ki=1(2θ)∏i:ki=2(1-3θ)

I'm starting it right, the joint density function?

Comment: [Similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3668880/321264) has been answered right? You don't mention where exactly you are having trouble in your questions, so it is difficult to give a proper answer.

Comment: You get all this help on the questions you ask, yet you never accept any answers.  Therefore, you will not get any additional help from me.

Comment: I'm having trouble to use factorization after.. to find the sufficient statistics

Comment: @heropup sorry I'm new in this website.. I didn't know I have to accept the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is the sample, then the likelihood is given by $$\mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x) = \prod_{i=1}^n \theta^{\mathbb 1(x_i = 0)} (2\theta)^{\mathbb 1(x_i = 1)} (1 - 3\theta)^{\mathbb 1(x_i = 2)},$$ where $$\mathbb 1(x_i = x) = \begin{cases}1, & x_i = x \\
0, & x_i \ne x \end{cases}$$ is an indicator function.  But since the sample size is $$n = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1(x_i = 0) + \mathbb 1(x_i = 1) + \mathbb 1(x_i = 2),$$ we can write this as $$\begin{align*} \mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x) &= \prod_{i=1}^n 2^{\mathbb 1(x_i = 1)} \theta^{\mathbb 1 (x_i = 0) + \mathbb 1 (x_i = 1)} (1 - 3\theta)^{\mathbb 1 (x_i = 2)} \\ &= 2^{\sum \mathbb 1(x_i = 1)} \theta^{\sum \mathbb 1(x_i = 0) + \mathbb 1(x_i = 1)} (1 - 3\theta)^{\sum \mathbb 1(x_i = 2)} \\
&= 2^{\sum \mathbb 1 (x_i = 1)} \theta^{n - \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1 (x_i = 2)} (1 - 3\theta)^{\sum \mathbb 1(x_i = 2)}. \end{align*}$$

Using the Factorization Theorem, we need to express this in the form $$h(\boldsymbol x) g(\boldsymbol T(\boldsymbol x) \mid \theta),$$ where $h$ is a function that does not depend on $\theta$, and the dependence of $g$ on the sample is only through the sufficient statistic $\boldsymbol T$.  Clearly, this suggests choosing $$h(\boldsymbol x) = 2^{\mathbb 1 (x_i = 1)}$$ since this is the only factor that does not depend on $\theta$.  Next, we can choose $$\boldsymbol T(\boldsymbol x) = T(\boldsymbol x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1 (x_i = 2),$$ thus $$g(T \mid \theta) = \theta^{n-T} (1-3\theta)^T = \theta^n (\theta^{-1} - 3)^T.$$  Our sufficient statistic, then, is simply the number of observations in the sample that equal $2$.

At first glance, this seems counterintuitive.  After all, should we not expect that the observed frequencies of $0$ and $1$ in addition to $2$ provide information about $\theta$?  However, this is not so.  First of all, we have a redundancy that arises from the fact that the sum of the frequencies must equal $n$, so at most, only one other category would be informative.  Without loss of generality, suppose this is the frequency of $0$ in addition to $2$.  But in fact, there is a second redundancy which becomes evident when we recall that $h$ was not chosen to be $1$, but $2^{\sum \mathbb 1(x_i = 1)}$.  This means there is no additional information about $\theta$ carried by the observed frequency of $1$ that is not already present in the sample through the observed frequencies of $0$ and $2$.

Comment: Got it, thank you @heropup .. one more question how did you simply this passage? (2θ)^(1(xi=1)) to this: θ1^((xi=0)+1(xi=1))

Comment: @Florent For convenience, let $s_k = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1 (x_i = k)$.  Then $$\theta^{s_0} (2\theta)^{s_1} = \theta^{s_0} 2^{s_1} \theta^{s_1} = 2^{s_1} \theta^{s_0 + s_1}.$$

Comment: oh ok thank you

Comment: I have this other problem: ) Let X1, . . . , Xn be a random sample from Uniform(0, θ). (a) Find the MVUE of E(X1) and Var(X1). The sufficient statistic is the max(X1...Xn) to find the MVUE of E(X1) and Var(X1)?